# How to save a object with vector or other standard library container to binary file in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, binary, fstream

the object like this:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    vector<int> i;
    //save other variable
};

void save(const A & a)
{
    //dosomething
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    save(a);
    return 0;
}
```

how to save it to a binary file?
in other word, how to write the save function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ofstream` and `copy` should suffice:

```
void save(const A & a)
{
    std::ofstream out_file("path/to/output/file", std::ios::binary);
    std::copy(a.i.begin(), a.i.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(out_file));
}
```

BTW you should probably avoid `using namespace std;`.

As pointed out in comments (thanks @Daniel Langr) this will work only for types with working implementation of `operator<<` for `ofstream` or its base classes

Comment: With the range based for, the copy-to-stream construction is less useful, especially if you want more formatting: `for (const auto& i: a.i) { out_file << i << ' '; };` (I know you can pass a separator to the iterator, but it doesn't make it clearer)

Comment: @stefaanv IMO it's the matter of taste here, many algorithms became semi-unuseful when ranged-based for loop came in C++11

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries that can help you with storing to files, but you can do it yourself too.

If you want the data in binary format in the file, then you can use the [ostream::write()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) function and for saving a container, at least the size should be stored.

So a very specific function would be

```
void save(const A & a)
{
    std::ofstream out_file("path/to/output/file", std::ios::binary);
    size_t sz = a.i.size();
    out_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&sz), sizeof(size_t));
    for (const auto& i: a.i) out_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof(int));
}
```

It would be better to pass the stream to the function and have the class save function call the container save function which in turns save each entry like this:

```
void save(std::ofstream& out, int i)
{
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof(int));
}

template<typename E> void save(std::ofstream& out, const std::vector<E>& v)
{
    size_t sz = v.size();
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&sz), sizeof(size_t));
    for (const auto& i: v) save(out, i);
}

void save(std::ofstream& out, const A & a)
{
    save(out, a.i);
}
```

This way, containers with entries of any type an be saved as long as there is a save function.